# how to run function on bootstrap modal pop-up (javascript, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a test, where each question is shown in a modal. The same modal, only the content inside is changed after each question. The result must also be shown in the same modal. To show the result, I use progressbar.js (http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/#examples). This is how it looks like in my index file:

```
 function result() {

    $('.progress1').css('display', 'block');

    var startColor = '#FC5B3F';
    var endColor = '#6FD57F';

    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('.progress1', {
        color: startColor,
        easing: 'easeIn',
        strokeWidth: 8,
        trailWidth: 0,
        duration: 2000,
        text: {
            value: '0',
            style: {
                color: '#000'
            }
        },

        step: function(state, bar) {
            bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
        }
    });


    function rangeToPercent(number, min, max){
        return ((number - min) / (max - min));
    }
    var value = rangeToPercent(counterAnswer, 0, counterQ)





    // This will determine the circumference of the circle
    circle.animate(value, {
        from: {color: startColor},
        to: {color: endColor}, 
        step: function(state, circle, bar) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
            console.log(circle);
            circle.setText((circle.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
        }
    });
}
```

After the last question is done (when the modal is not visible yet) I change modal content to

```
 <h2 style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'>Your score is:</h3><br>
 <div style='margin: auto;' class='progress1' value='0'></div>
```

and add new class to the modal
      `$('#myModalTest').addClass('result');` .
In my script I have:
          `$(".result").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
         result();
     });`

But this doesn't work.
I tried to put `result();` in `setTimeOut` (and run it without `$(".result").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {result();});`), but then it runs 4 times creating 4 circles (I have no idea why).
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the modal content dynamically?

We had this problem and got it working by using adding this at the end of the modal content:

```
(function() {
    // Your code here
})();
```

When the content is loaded by the modal it will run the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Having read through your question again, I think the code to add the shown event to the modal is being run before you add the result class to it.

So page loads and runs (presumably in a script tag at the end of the page?):

```
$(".result").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    result();
});
```

The selector **$(".result")** won't find anything at this point so your shown event is not bound on anything.

You then add the class **result** to the modal

```
$('#myModalTest').addClass('result');
```

and fire up the modal but the modal doesn't have the event wired up.

I *think* you need to either do this in the first place:

```
$("#myModalTest").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    result();
});
```

because why is the **result** class needed? Or do:

```
$('#myModalTest').addClass('result').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    result();
});
```

when you add the class to add the event.

I havent tested any of that but the logic seems right, depending on what is in the code I can't see.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I found another way. I created a separate modal just for result, added a rule to show it as the last modal (after question counter is the right number) and then `$("#result").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {result();});` started working properly)

Comment: Ok, sounds like the above was the problem then, missed out on my points :(